# Google Chrome is not working after upgrade on Dell systems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome

We have updated Google Chrome from 78 stable to the latest version 85 stable official release on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Dell systems. After the upgrade, we were unable to access any URLs -- no error showing in Chrome, it's just showing as it is loading. Sometimes it is crashes.

Tried to open in terminal and enable logging, getting the below nss error, but we already have nss 3.26 installed.

```
FATAL: nss_util.cc(657) NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >=3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
```

We have downgraded to version 78 and uninstalled Chrome and re-installed but it is still not working.

When we performed the Chrome update, after that we updated the kernel on the systems. Tried booting system with old kernel and checked but not working.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Try `apt-get install libnss3` and then opening Chrome.

Comment: @cutrightjm -- I have checked libnss3 had already installed, After couple of reboots it's started working. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Please post what worked for you if you did anything else to get this working to help out future people.